# Networkx: get_edge_data returning unexpected result when ca;lled on MultiDiGraph

Tags: python, networkx

I am using Python's popular network library `networkx`. From the following code I expect the printed statements to be equivalent.

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()
mgraph =  nx.MultiDiGraph()

for G in [graph, mgraph]:
    G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=4.7)

print(graph.get_edge_data(1, 2))
print(mgraph.get_edge_data(1,2))
```

However I obtain the following:

```
{'weight': 4.7}
{0: {'weight': 4.7}}
```

Why is that extra `0` key added in the case of the multidirectional graph? What does it correspond to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `MultiDiGraph` allows multiple edges.  Each edge may have its own attributes.  In your example what it is telling you is that in the `Graph` case, the edge (of which there can be only one) has weight 4.7.  But in the `MultiDiGraph` case it is telling you that the edge which is indexed by 0 (and there happens to be only this single edge) has weight 4.7.

Try this to get a bit more clarity where we add the edge again, but with a different weight:

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()
mgraph =  nx.MultiDiGraph()

for G in [graph, mgraph]:
    G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=4.7)
    G.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 5)  #are we overwriting an edge, or adding an extra edge?

print(graph.get_edge_data(1, 2))
print(mgraph.get_edge_data(1,2))
```

which gives the output

```
>{'weight': 5}
>{0: {'weight': 4.7}, 1: {'weight': 5}}
```

showing that in the `Graph` case, the edge attribute gets overwritten (since there is only one edge), but in the `MultiDiGraph` case a second edge is added with index `1`.